# Writing Thrift schemas: non-flattened struct constants, makes me repetitive

Tags: thrift

I am trying to use thrift's `Const` feature to create stub data for my models. For example:

```
struct Book {
    1: i32 id
}

struct Author {
    1: Book book
}

const Book bookEx1 = { // example instance of Book
    'id': 1
}

const Author AuthorEx1 = { /// example instance of Author
    //'book': { 'id': 1 }  // This is a copy from above, but works well
    'book': BookEx1  // this doesn't work, see below
}
```

The above example, when compiled, throws an error:

```
$ thrift -v -gen js:ts model.thrift
Scanning model.thrift for includes
Parsing model.thrift for types
[FAILURE:model.thrift:17] type error: const "AuthorEx1.book" was declared as struct/xception
```

Problem: I want to refer to other defined const structs by already defined structs from before (e.g. bookEx1) instead of flattening the values. How can I do that?

I use Thrift 0.9.2.

Comment: Cross-posted to their issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3316

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Comment: It is hard to maintain these fixtures, so I got rid of them. Instead I expose a dependency-less mini-implementation of my service for use in unit tests.